# Sprax Enterprise Architect auto generate getter and setter methods in php

Tags: php, getter-setter

I am using Sparx Enterprise Architect to create a domain model in php.  When I generate the code, EA only produces the classes with the attributes and does not automatically create the getter and setter methods.  has anyone one else had this issues and found a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Auto-generated getter and setter do not really improve the code or anything. The generated properties are probably made public - you are free to change them when you add logic to the getter or setter.

Comment: is that opinion or fact?

Comment: `function setStuff($var) { $this->stuff = $stuff; }` vs. `public $stuff;` - no real difference.